# Cómo agregar objetos a archivo binario y eliminar objeto a través de funciones en python

Tags: python, archivo

Mi programa consiste en agregar elementos a un archivo binario usando una función, el modo de apertura del archivo binario está en "a+b" por lo que debería agregarse al final del archivo ya existente, pero mi problema está en que no se está agregando correctamente el contenido al archivo sino sobrescribe un objeto(en caso de tener ya un objeto) , de forma que no me deja tener más de 1 objeto en el archivo binario. Pensé y también es probable que tuviera un error al imprimir el contenido del archivo binario, mi código es el siguiente:

```
import os
import pickle

class Temas():
    def __init__(self,autor,title):
        self.autor=autor
        self.titulo=title

def Agregar(temas):
    archivo=open("InventarioMusica.dat","a+b")
    print("Ingrese nombre del autor y titulo del tema que desea agregar")
    title=input("Titulo: ")
    autor=input("Autor: ")
    temas.append(Temas(autor,title))
    os.system("cls")
    pickle.dump(temas,archivo)
    print("El tema fue agregado con exito")
    os.system("pause")
    archivo.close()

def Visualizar():
    print("Los temas en el sistemas son los siguientes: ")
    if os.stat("InventarioMusica.dat").st_size == 0:
        print("» No se tiene ningun tema en el sistema")
    else:
        archivo=open("InventarioMusica.dat","rb")
        contenido=pickle.load(archivo)
        archivo.close()
        for i in contenido:
            print("» TItulo: ",i.titulo)
            print("» Autor: ",i.autor)
    os.system("pause")

def Eliminar():
    pass

temas=[]
while True:
    os.system("color 0f")
    print("Inventario de Temas Musicales:")
    print("» Ingrese 1 para agregar un tema nuevo")
    print("» Ingrese 2 para visualizar los temas del inventario")
    print("» Ingrese 3 para Borrar un determinado tema (busqueda por titulo)")
    print("» Ingrese 4 para terminar")
    opc=int(input("Opcion: "))
    os.system("cls")
    if opc == 1:
        Agregar(temas)
    elif opc == 2:
        Visualizar()
    elif opc == 3:
        Eliminar()
    elif opc == 4:
        break
    else:
        os.system("color 4f")
        print("Se introdujo un valor fuera de las opciones")
        os.system("pause")
    os.system("cls")
```

Mi otro problema es el de eliminar un determinado objeto del archivo, no tengo muy claro como codificar la eliminación de un determinado contenido, esta es la función que tengo incompleta:

```
def Eliminar():
    encontro=False
    print("Ingrese a continuacion, titulo del tema que desea Eliminar")
    delete=input("Titulo: ")
    os.system("cls")
    #se ingresa por teclado en la variable "delete" el nombre del titulo a eliminar
```

Es la primera vez que estoy trabajando con archivos binarios, busque pero no encontré solución a estos problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He estado mirando tu código, y tienes varios problemas.

1. `Agregar(temas)` `temas` siempre esta vacío, ya que se declaro como tal.
2. Modo `ab`: Significa añadir nuevo valor/objeto al final del archivo en modo binario(pero recuerda que necesitamos mantener una estructura tipo lista) por lo cual `wb`(sobrescribir todo) es el que más se ajusta.

Por otra parte te recomiendo dividir el código en funciones, por ejemplo, listar todos los datos podría ser una función o guardar nuevos datos.

La parte de eliminar un tema es fácil, la idea es simplemente buscar en los temas el tema que haga `match` con el titulo que se ha introducido por teclado.

```
def Eliminar():
    temas = get_temas()  # Obtenemos todos los temas de nuevo.
    print("Ingrese a continuacion, titulo del tema que desea Eliminar")
    delete = input("Titulo: ")
    # Buscar el tema por titulo dentro de la lista "temas"
    tema_a_borrar = next((tema for tema in temas if tema.titulo == delete), None)
    # Hay un tema con el mismo titulo a borrar.
    if tema_a_borrar:
        temas = [tema for tema in temas if tema.titulo != tema_a_borrar.titulo]
        guardar_temas(temas)
        print("Tema: {} borrado con exito.".format(tema_a_borrar.titulo))
    else:
        print("No se ha encontrado ningun tema...")
    os.system('pause')
```

He hecho unos cambios en tu código, que no solo se ve más limpio si no que es también más simple de mantener y hacer un cambio si se necesita.

Dicho esto el resultado final seria algo así

```
import os
import pickle

# Nombre de archivo.
FILE_NAME = 'InventarioMusica.dat'

class Temas:

    def __init__(self, autor, title):
        self.autor = autor
        self.titulo = title


def Agregar():
    temas = get_temas() # Obtener todos los temas
    print('Ingrese nombre del autor y titulo del tema que desea agregar')
    title = input('Titulo: ')
    autor = input('Autor: ')
    temas.append(Temas(autor, title))
    os.system('cls')
    # Llamamos a la funcion para guardar los temas
    guardar_temas(temas=temas)
    print('El tema fue agregado con exito')
    os.system('pause')


def Visualizar():
    temas = get_temas() # Obtener todos los temas
    print('Los temas en el sistemas son los siguientes: ')
    if not temas:
        print("» No se tiene ningun tema en el sistema")
    else:
        for tema in temas:
            print ("» Titulo: ", tema.titulo)
            print ("» Autor: ", tema.autor)
    os.system('pause')


def Eliminar():
    temas = get_temas() # Obtener todos los temas
    print("Ingrese a continuacion, titulo del tema que desea Eliminar")
    delete = input("Titulo: ")
    # Buscar el tema por titulo dentro de la lista "temas"
    tema_a_borrar = next((tema for tema in temas if tema.titulo == delete), None)
    # Hay un tema con el mismo titulo a borrar.
    if tema_a_borrar:
        temas = [tema for tema in temas if tema.titulo != tema_a_borrar.titulo]
        guardar_temas(temas)
        print("Tema: {} borrado con exito.".format(tema_a_borrar.titulo))
    else:
        print("No se ha encontrado ningun tema...")
    os.system('pause')


def guardar_temas(temas):
    # with se encarga automaticamente de cerrar el archivo al terminal.
    with open(FILE_NAME, 'wb') as archivo:  
        pickle.dump(temas, archivo)

def get_temas():
    # Mirar si el archivo no esta vacio:
    if os.path.exists(FILE_NAME):
        if os.stat(FILE_NAME).st_size > 0:
            with open(FILE_NAME, 'rb') as archivo:
                contenido = pickle.load(archivo)
                return contenido
        # Si esta vacio
    return []



while True:
    os.system('color 0f')
    print('Inventario de Temas Musicales:')
    print("» Ingrese 1 para agregar un tema nuevo")
    print("» Ingrese 2 para visualizar los temas del inventario")
    print("» Ingrese 3 para Borrar un determinado tema (busqueda por titulo)")
    print("» Ingrese 4 para terminar")
    opc = int(input('Opcion: ')) # Cuidado con esta parte, no siempre se puede convertir a entero
    os.system('cls')
    if opc == 1:
        Agregar()
    elif opc == 2:
        Visualizar()
    elif opc == 3:
        Eliminar()
    elif opc == 4:
        break
    else:
        os.system('color 4f')
        print('Se introdujo un valor fuera de las opciones')
        os.system('pause')
    os.system('cls')
```

Espero que te sirva.

Un saludo.

Comment: No debería crecer al visualizarse, ya que no se trata de ninguna operación, `temas` estará vació o no dependiendo si hubo registros anteriores o no. No consigo entenderte bien a que te refieres.

Comment: Me confundi. Tienes razón. Borrare el comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un problema con el código de grabación:

```
temas.append(Temas(autor,title))
os.system("cls")
pickle.dump(temas,archivo)
```

temas es una lista que siempre crece; nunca pierde elementos o queda vacia. Cada vez que haces un `pickle.dump` estas grabando la lista completa. Como abristes el archivo en modo "a+b", esta lista que grabaste se agrega a la cola de las listas previas.

O sea, el archivo queda así (partiendo de un archivo vacio). Cada linea corresponde a un `pickle.dump()`:

```
Gen 0 -> []
Gen 1 -> [(Titulo1, Autor1)]
Gen 2 -> [(Titulo1, Autor1)]
         [(Titulo1, Autor1) (Titulo2, Autor2)]
Gen 3 -> [(Titulo1, Autor1)]
         [(Titulo1, Autor1) (Titulo2, Autor2)]
         [(Titulo1, Autor1) (Titulo2, Autor2) (Titulo3, Autor3]
```

Cuando tratas de leer de vuelta la lista de temas, el `pickle.load` solo carga el primer objeto del archivo, que es una lista con un sólo tema. Por eso da la apariencia que el archivo solo contiene un item.

Cada vez que ejecutas `pickle.load` se carga un nuevo objeto desde el archivo, por lo que eventualmente llegarías a la última versión de la lista de temas.

Lo más sano, sin embargo, es abrir el archivo en modo "w+b". El modo "w" borra cualquier cosa que haya de antes. El archivo asi, sólo contiene la última versión de la lista de temas, y basta con un solo `pickle.load` para recuperar la ultima versión.

**El problema de la eliminación**

Eliminalo de la lista de temas y luego graba la lista en el archivo, tal cual lo haces al agregar un tema.